# Git clone with personal access token

Tags: ruby, switch-statement, calculator

when I am trying to make git clone in windows shell or cmd it gives me error of authentication, after that I read that I should make personal token instead of password
then I tried to git clone several times with the token but it still gives me the same error
can anyone help ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have correctly generated your ssh keys and added your public key to your account, you should receive a prompt of some sort, asking if you expected to connect to some specific IP address, and then adding that IP address to trusted addresses when you answer yes. If you still get a message about the authentication failing, it could be a matter of you having made a mistake while adding your public key to your account, or git not finding your private key in the expected place. Without getting a look at the specific error message, I couldn't really say, but I would recommend reviewing the steps you took to add the public key to your account.